# Ruby transform hash into a running total of values

Tags: ruby, hash, reduce, inject

I have a hash

```rb
{:a => 2, :b => 8, :c => 10, :d => 40 }
```

I want to modify the hash so that the values represent a running total.

```rb
{:a => 2, :b => 10, :c => 20, :d => 60 }
```

I've gone down a few paths, but haven't found the right answer.  Some of the things I've tried.

```rb
data.inject({}) { |result, (k,v)| result[k] = v+ result.values.compact.sum; result }

=> {:a=>2, :b=>10, :c=>22, :d=>74}
```

I'm obviously not quite grasping how the result is accumulating in that inject. I'm using compact due to the first iteration of k being nil.

I can get the values as an array like so

```rb
data.inject([]) { |result, element| result << result.last.to_i + element.last }

=> [2, 10, 20, 60]
```

I can't work out how to modify this to work similarly with a hash.

I can do it like this, but it doesn't seem like the right/most efficient way to do it.

```rb
totals = data.inject([]) { |result, element| result << result.last.to_i + element.last }

=> [2, 10, 20, 60]

data.map.with_index { |(k,v),i| [k,totals[i]] }.to_h

=> {:a=>2, :b=>10, :c=>20, :d=>60}
```

Appreciate any help I can get here.

Answer (score 6):

Given that you know the order of the keys you can simply write

```
h= { :a => 2, :b => 8, :c => 10, :d => 40 }
```

```
cumulative = 0
h.transform_values { |v| cumulative += v }
  #=> {:a=>2, :b=>10, :c=>20, :d=>60}
```

See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

Comment: Clever use of `transform_values` (which I rarely remember exists).

Answer (score 0):

Your "`inject` and `map.with_index`" is close but you can combine them:

```
data.inject({}) { |h, (k, v)| h.merge(k => v + h.values.last.to_i) }
```

or with less copying:

```
data.inject({}) { |h, (k, v)| h.merge!(k => v + h.values.last.to_i) }
```

or perhaps:

```
data.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v + h.values.last.to_i }
```

`h` starts off empty so `h.values` can be empty so `h.values.last.nil?` will happen, hence the `#to_i` call to "hide" the `nil` test and simplify the block.

Answer (score -2):

### Hashes and Ordering

Hashes are not guaranteed to be in sorted order, so your premise that you can keep a running total are (in principle) invalid unless you are sorting the keys before passing the values to #inject or #reduce. However, MRI Ruby often keeps a Hash in insertion order, but trust that at your own risk.

### Solution

Setting aside the sort-order of your Hash, which you could address with #sort or #sort_by and a little refactoring if you choose, I would modify the original Hash in place like this in Ruby 3.0.2:

```rb
hash = {:a => 2, :b => 8, :c => 10, :d => 40 }

# Note that positional argument `_1` is the
# accumulator, and `_2` is the value.
hash = hash.keys.zip(
  hash.values.inject([]) { _1 << _2 + _1&.last.to_i }
).to_h;
hash
#=> {:a=>2, :b=>10, :c=>20, :d=>60}
```

If you don't want to assign back to the same Hash, or want to assign the result somewhere else, you can do that too. However, as I understood the question to be about in-place modification of your Hash, assigning the result of the expression back to *hash* seemed like the easiest thing to do.

Comment: "MRI Ruby often keeps a Hash in insertion order, but trust that at your own risk" is not quite true. Ruby has guaranteed Hash order since 1.9.3 (["Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted."](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html)) and the docs have been slowly getting more explicit about over the years.

Comment: @muistooshort See also [Entry Order](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Hash.html#class-Hash-label-Entry+Order).  There are clearly cases where the key order will change, and encouraging people to *rely* on original insertion order when they're making changes to a Hash is, IMHO, potentially risky in the general case but doesn't affect this particular solution. Whether insertion order is preserved in JRuby, TruffleRuby, Rubinius, etc. is an exercise for the user, but the point is that insertion-order is an *implementation* choice for MRI Ruby, not a property of hashes in general. YMMV.

Comment: "Whether insertion order is preserved in JRuby, TruffleRuby, Rubinius, etc. is an exercise for the user" – It's a pretty trivial exercise, since as of Ruby 1.9.3, enumeration in insertion order is part of the language specification.

Comment: MRI is as close to a real specification of Ruby there is and it documents how hashes are ordered. Anything that doesn't maintain insertion order of hashes isn't really Ruby at all. I'd agree that a hash might not be the best choice if order is important but it isn't an implementation choice, it is specified behavior.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're both missing the basic computer science point, as well as the very clear Ruby documentation I linked to above. Consider `h = {a: 1, b: 2}; h.delete :a; h[:a] = 1; h #=> {:b=>2, :a=>1}`.  In production applications, relying on Hash keys being pre-sorted is risky, although it's often fine for toy problems or short examples when you *know* that the original insertion order won't change.

Comment: I don't really understand your example. Is it intended to be counter-example? Because it clearly demonstrates that insertion order is preserved, just ike the language specification says it should.

Comment: @muistooshort: In this case, you don't even have to refer to YARV. The requirement is [in the specification](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/core/hash/keys_spec.rb#L6-L14), in other words, the property is guaranteed to be a property of hashes in general, not an implementation choice for MRI Ruby. (Also note that MRI has been obsolete for 8 years, and did in fact *not* preserve insertion order, because that requirement was only added for Ruby 1.9, and MRI never implemented Ruby 1.9; it stopped halfway through development of the never-released Ruby 1.8.8.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag & muistooshort: You are both bike-shedding, and you know it. The “specification” itself says: “It is not a standardized specification like the ISO one, and does not aim to become one.” It also refers to the reference implementation as “MRI.” If arguing minor semantics makes you feel better go right ahead, but this thread is clearly no longer about legitimately clarifying any points or interpretations from my answer, so you’ll have to carry on without me.